# Display default date based on time in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, time, datepicker

I needs to display date in "datepicker" based on some timing like, if the local time exceeds 12 pm means it should be select tomorrow date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help

```
var now = new Date(Date.now());
var formatted = now.getHours();
if(formatted >= 12){
  $( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: +1 });
}
else{
  $( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: new Date() });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", new Date());
// Or on the init
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: new Date() });
```

Use this to show current date.

Comment: Thanks, But i want to set date if current time exceeds 12pm.